# Show that $G$ is not solvable iff it contains a normal non trivial subgroup with $H=H'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that $G$ is not solvable iff it contains a normal non trivial subgroup $H$ with $H=H'$.

$$$$

I have done the following :

it holds that $H'=H^{(1)}=[H,H]$, derived group.

We assume that $G$ is solvable. Then each subgroup and quotient group of $G$ is solvable. So $H$ is solvable.

A group $H$ is solvable iff the derived series ends with the trivial group.

That cannot hold with a non trivial group $H$ with $H=H'$, because all derived groups $H^{(i+1)}=[H^{(i)}, H^{(i)}]$ are equal to $H$ which is non trivial.

So we get a contradiction.

Therefore $G$ cannot be solvable.

$$$$

Is everything correct and complete? Or isn't this enough for the *iff* statement?

Comment: It seems to me that you have proved that there cannot exist such a non-trivial subgroup $H$ in a solvable $G$, but you have not proved the converse, that is, that there exists such a subgroup in any non-solvable group.

Comment: Could you give me a hint for the converse? Do we do the same just from the other way around? @J.Darné

Comment: Consider the derived series $G \ge G' \ge G'' \ge \cdots$. If the gorup is not solvable, then this series cannot reach the trivial subgroup. So, since $G$ is finite, one of the groups $H$ in the derived series must satisfy $H'=H$. Note that this argument (and also the result) fails when $G$ is infinite.

Comment: The best proof is the one indicated above by Derek Holt. Here's another one though. We'll prove that if G is not soluble then it has a non-trivial characteristic perfect subgroup. Induct on $|G|$, the base case ($G = A_5$) being trivially true since non-abelian simple groups are perfect. Now if $G = G'$ we are done so we may assume that $G' < G$. If $G'$ is soluble then $G$ is soluble (since it is soluble-by-abelian). Thus we may further assume $G' <G$. By the induction hypothesis applied to $G'$ there exists a non-trivial perfect $H$ characteristic in $G'$. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Well, the suggested proof by induction is essentially the same as Derek Holt's (just a wee bit more fleshed out). Anyway...

Comment: @the_fox: I agree it is essentially the same proof. I want to remark though that for the inductive proof, you could take $|G| = 1$ as the base case, since in that case the result is vacuously true.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why that H  is normal?

Comment: @Jam All subgroups in the derived series are characteristic and hence normal.

Comment: @DerekHolt Didnt know that ! Thanks. Any suggestion where to read about normal series in general. Seems everyone is giving  a brief exposure on basic algebra texts. THough i havent checked Dummit n Foote.